# Easily check whether an objective was recorded in other variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have customer id, product_id1 and product_id2. The data have customers' purchasing information and sorted by customer and time so 1st row of each customer is the oldest record. 
 
product_id1 includes purchased items
product_id2 includes items that I want to know whether each of item is purchased before (check from the product_id1).

For each item in product_id2 for each customer, I want to create dummy variable that indicated whether each of item in product_id2 is purchased in the past 
 In other words, a value in product_id2 at nth row has been shown at least one time in 1~(n-1)th rows in product_id1, the purchased_before is 1 otherwise 0.

So I want to create "purchased_before" column.

I can do it by using for loop but is there any efficient way?

Data is as below,

```
customer id      product_id1   product_id2     purchased_before
    1             112             113                 0
    1             115             114                 0
    1             113             113                 0
    1             114             113                 1
    1             115             114                 1
    ....
    2             112             115                 0
    2             115             112                 1
    2             113             113                 0
```

Comment: Anyone can answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can solved using a *non-equi join* and aggregating while joining:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[
  # add "time variable", i.e., row id to identify earlier purchases
  , rn := .I][
    # create new column with ...
    , cnt_of_earlier_purchases := 
      # ... the result of the non-equi join aggregate
      DT[DT, on = .(customer_id, product_id1 = product_id2, rn < rn), .N, by = .EACHI]$N][]

   customer_id product_id1 product_id2 rn cnt_of_earlier_purchases
1:           1         112         113  1                        0
2:           1         115         114  2                        0
3:           1         113         113  3                        0
4:           1         114         113  4                        1
5:           1         115         114  5                        1
6:           2         112         115  6                        0
7:           2         115         112  7                        1
8:           2         112         113  8                        0
9:           2         115         112  9                        2
```

The new column contains the count of purchases before the actual purchase.

Note that a modified sample data set with multiple purchases has been used to demonstrate the effect of counting the purchases.

Alternatively, a logical value can be appended instead of the count:

```
setDT(DT)[, rn := .I][
  , purchased_before := 
    DT[DT, on = .(customer_id, product_id1 = product_id2, rn < rn), .N, by = .EACHI]$N > 0][]
```

> ```
>    customer_id product_id1 product_id2 rn purchased_before
> 1:           1         112         113  1            FALSE
> 2:           1         115         114  2            FALSE
> 3:           1         113         113  3            FALSE
> 4:           1         114         113  4             TRUE
> 5:           1         115         114  5             TRUE
> 6:           2         112         115  6            FALSE
> 7:           2         115         112  7             TRUE
> 8:           2         112         113  8            FALSE
> 9:           2         115         112  9             TRUE
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"customer_id      product_id1   product_id2     purchased_before
    1             112             113                 0
    1             115             114                 0
    1             113             113                 0
    1             114             113                 1
    1             115             114                 1
    2             112             115                 0
    2             115             112                 1
    2             112             113                 0
    2             115             112                 0", select = 1:3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! But I have a question. if I want to use certain (e.g, 115 as below) value instead of product_id2, how to do it?

setDT(DT)[, rn := .I][
  , purchased_before := 
    DT[DT, on = .(customer_id, product_id1 == 115 , rn < rn), .N, by = .EACHI]$N > 0][]

Comment: I mean, I want to use certain value instead of the variable, product_id2, in the code as I changed with "product_id1==115" above.

Comment: Do you want to filter the result because you are only interested in a certain product?

Comment: I just thought it would be simple. Isn't it?

Comment: Please, try `setDT(DT)[, rn := .I][
  , purchased_before := 
    DT[DT, on = .(customer_id, product_id1 = product_id2, rn < rn), .N, by = .EACHI]$N > 0][product_id2 == 115]
`

Comment: Sorry. let me clear again with the code as below, 
setDT(DT)[  , rn := .I][
    , cnt_of_earlier_purchases := 
      DT[DT, on = .(customer_id, product_id1 = product_id2, rn < rn), .N, by = .EACHI]$N][]


With the code, for example, 3rd row value of 'cnt_of_earlier_purchases' is counting product_id1 == 113 in first~second row. Right?

Comment: Then If I want to just want to count  product_id1 == 113 in all rows to creat new variable (let's say var name as "purchased_113_before"), below code does not work.

setDT(DT)[  , rn := .I][
    , cnt_of_earlier_purchases := 
      DT[DT, on = .(customer_id, product_id1 == 113, rn < rn), .N, by = .EACHI]$N][]

How to do it?

Comment: The `on` parameter describes which columns are to be used in the join and how. So filtering doesn't work here. To be honest, I don't understand what you are after. Perhaps it would be become clearer (at least to me) if you could post a new question showing the expected result?

Comment: ! sorry if I keep bothering you. I am urgent. Can you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799054/how-to-create-rank-variable-under-certain-condition

Hope you can answer this questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`dplyr`:

```
df %>%
    group_by(customer_id) %>%
    mutate(purchased_before = sapply(row_number(), function(x) {
               ifelse(product_id2[x] %in% product_id1[1:(x-1)], 1, 0)
           })
    )
```

`base R`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$customer_id), function(x) {
    x$purchased_before <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(y) {
        ifelse(x$product_id2[y] %in% x$product_id1[1:(y-1)], 1, 0)
    })
    x
}))
```

The main thing here is looping through the row numbers in the `product_id2` column and using those row numbers to access the `product_id2` value at a given index, along with `product_id1` values from 1 until that given index. Once you have those values, you can carry out a simple `match` operator inside an `ifelse`. If there is a match, you assign `1`; or `0` otherwise.

I hope this proves useful.