# How to create a rank variable under certain conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, plyr

My data contain time variable and chosen brand variable as below. time indicates the shopping time and chosenbrand indicates the purchased brand at the time.

With this data, I would like to create rank variable as shown third column, fourth column, and so on.

The rank of brands (e.g., brand1 - brand3) should be based on past 36 hours. So, to calculate the rank for the second row, which has shoptime as `"2013-09-01 08:54:00 UTC"` the rank should be based on all `chosenbrand` values within 36 hours before the time. (`brand1` in second row should not be in the 36 hours)

Therefore, rank_brand1, rank_brand2, rank_brand3, rank_bran4,,, are my desired variables.

If I want to create rank_brand5, rank_brand6 as well...

Is there any simple way?

In addition, if I want to do it by individual (if each customer has several purchased history), how to do that?

Data is as below,

```
          shoptime          chosenbrand  rank_brand1 rank_brand2 rank_brand3, ...
  2013-09-01 08:35:00 UTC      brand1          NA         NA          NA
  2013-09-01 08:54:00 UTC      brand1          1          NA          NA
  2013-09-01 09:07:00 UTC      brand2          1          2          NA
  2013-09-01 09:08:00 UTC      brand3          1          2          3
  2013-09-01 09:11:00 UTC      brand5          1          2          3
  2013-09-01 09:14:00 UTC      brand2          1          2          3
  2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC      brand6          1          1          3
  2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC      brand2          1          1          3
  2013-09-01 09:29:00 UTC      brand2          2          1          3
  2013-09-01 09:32:00 UTC      brand4          2          1          3
```

Here is code for data

```
dat <- data.frame(shoptime = c("2013-09-01 08:35:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 08:54:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:07:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-01 09:08:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:11:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:14:00 UTC",
                           "2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-01 09:29:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:32:00 UTC"),
                  chosenbrand = c("brand1", "brand1", "brand2", "brand3", "brand5", "brand2", "brand6", "brand2"  ,  "brand2"  ,   "brand4"   ),
                  rank_brand1 = NA,
                  rank_brand2 = NA,
                 rank_brand3 = NA,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I need to count with observations within recent 36 hours. Any idea about that?

Comment: please anyone can help?

Comment: Why `NA` for `rank_brand2` in 1st row? Per the data provided by your `band1`, `band2` and `band3` are available within 36 hours of 1st row.

Comment: 1st row rank_brand1 should be NA. I just corrected. Since there is no prior history before 1st row, all should be NA. And there history from the second row

Comment: Concerning your add-on question, please, ask a separate question and provide sample data which includes the purchase history of several customers. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky one. The solution below uses *non-equi joins* to aggregate by 36 hours periods, `dcast()` to reshape from long to wide format, and a second join with the original `dat`. There can be an arbitrary number of brands.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

setDT(dat)[, shoptime := as_datetime(shoptime)]
setorder(dat, shoptime) # not required, just for convenience of observers
dat[.(lb = shoptime - hours(36), ub = shoptime), on = .(shoptime >= lb, shoptime < ub), 
    nomatch = 0L, by = .EACHI, 
    .SD[, .N, by = brand][, rank := frank(-N, ties.method="dense")]][
      , dcast(unique(.SD[, -1]), shoptime ~ brand, value.var = "rank")][
        dat, on = "shoptime"]
```

> ```
>                shoptime brand1 brand2 brand3 brand5 brand6  brand
>  1: 2013-09-01 08:35:00     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA brand1
>  2: 2013-09-01 08:54:00      1     NA     NA     NA     NA brand1
>  3: 2013-09-01 09:07:00      1     NA     NA     NA     NA brand2
>  4: 2013-09-01 09:08:00      1      2     NA     NA     NA brand3
>  5: 2013-09-01 09:11:00      1      2      2     NA     NA brand5
>  6: 2013-09-01 09:14:00      1      2      2      2     NA brand2
>  7: 2013-09-01 09:26:00      1      1      2      2     NA brand6
>  8: 2013-09-01 09:26:00      1      1      2      2     NA brand2
>  9: 2013-09-01 09:29:00      2      1      3      3      3 brand2
> 10: 2013-09-01 09:32:00      2      1      3      3      3 brand4
> ```

#### Explanation

```
dat[.(lb = shoptime - hours(36), ub = shoptime), on = .(shoptime >= lb, shoptime < ub), 
    nomatch = 0L, by = .EACHI, 
    .SD[, .N, by = brand][, rank := frank(-N, ties.method="dense")]]
```

returns the aggregated results per 36 hours periods:

> ```
>                shoptime            shoptime  brand N rank
>  1: 2013-08-30 20:54:00 2013-09-01 08:54:00 brand1 1    1
>  2: 2013-08-30 21:07:00 2013-09-01 09:07:00 brand1 2    1
>  3: 2013-08-30 21:08:00 2013-09-01 09:08:00 brand1 2    1
>  4: 2013-08-30 21:08:00 2013-09-01 09:08:00 brand2 1    2
>  5: 2013-08-30 21:11:00 2013-09-01 09:11:00 brand1 2    1
>  6: 2013-08-30 21:11:00 2013-09-01 09:11:00 brand2 1    2
>  7: 2013-08-30 21:11:00 2013-09-01 09:11:00 brand3 1    2
>  8: 2013-08-30 21:14:00 2013-09-01 09:14:00 brand1 2    1
>  9: 2013-08-30 21:14:00 2013-09-01 09:14:00 brand2 1    2
> 10: 2013-08-30 21:14:00 2013-09-01 09:14:00 brand3 1    2
> 11: 2013-08-30 21:14:00 2013-09-01 09:14:00 brand5 1    2
> 12: 2013-08-30 21:26:00 2013-09-01 09:26:00 brand1 2    1
> 13: 2013-08-30 21:26:00 2013-09-01 09:26:00 brand2 2    1
> 14: 2013-08-30 21:26:00 2013-09-01 09:26:00 brand3 1    2
> 15: 2013-08-30 21:26:00 2013-09-01 09:26:00 brand5 1    2
> 16: 2013-08-30 21:26:00 2013-09-01 09:26:00 brand1 2    1
> 17: 2013-08-30 21:26:00 2013-09-01 09:26:00 brand2 2    1
> 18: 2013-08-30 21:26:00 2013-09-01 09:26:00 brand3 1    2
> 19: 2013-08-30 21:26:00 2013-09-01 09:26:00 brand5 1    2
> 20: 2013-08-30 21:29:00 2013-09-01 09:29:00 brand1 2    2
> 21: 2013-08-30 21:29:00 2013-09-01 09:29:00 brand2 3    1
> 22: 2013-08-30 21:29:00 2013-09-01 09:29:00 brand3 1    3
> 23: 2013-08-30 21:29:00 2013-09-01 09:29:00 brand5 1    3
> 24: 2013-08-30 21:29:00 2013-09-01 09:29:00 brand6 1    3
> 25: 2013-08-30 21:32:00 2013-09-01 09:32:00 brand1 2    2
> 26: 2013-08-30 21:32:00 2013-09-01 09:32:00 brand2 4    1
> 27: 2013-08-30 21:32:00 2013-09-01 09:32:00 brand3 1    3
> 28: 2013-08-30 21:32:00 2013-09-01 09:32:00 brand5 1    3
> 29: 2013-08-30 21:32:00 2013-09-01 09:32:00 brand6 1    3
>                shoptime            shoptime  brand N rank
> ```

Then, this intermediate result is reshaped from long to wide format:

```
dat[.(lb = shoptime - hours(36), ub = shoptime), on = .(shoptime >= lb, shoptime < ub), 
    nomatch = 0L, by = .EACHI, 
    .SD[, .N, by = brand][, rank := frank(-N, ties.method="dense")]][
      , dcast(unique(.SD[, -1]), shoptime ~ brand, value.var = "rank")]
```

> ```
>               shoptime brand1 brand2 brand3 brand5 brand6
> 1: 2013-09-01 08:54:00      1     NA     NA     NA     NA
> 2: 2013-09-01 09:07:00      1     NA     NA     NA     NA
> 3: 2013-09-01 09:08:00      1      2     NA     NA     NA
> 4: 2013-09-01 09:11:00      1      2      2     NA     NA
> 5: 2013-09-01 09:14:00      1      2      2      2     NA
> 6: 2013-09-01 09:26:00      1      1      2      2     NA
> 7: 2013-09-01 09:29:00      2      1      3      3      3
> 8: 2013-09-01 09:32:00      2      1      3      3      3
> ```

The final right join with the original `dat` data frame completes the missing rows and columns (see code and result above).

#### Data

```
dat <- data.frame(
  shoptime = c("2013-09-01 08:35:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 08:54:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:07:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-01 09:08:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:11:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:14:00 UTC",
               "2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-01 09:29:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:32:00 UTC"),
  brand = c("brand1", "brand1", "brand2", "brand3", "brand5", "brand2", "brand6", "brand2"  ,  "brand2"  ,   "brand4"   ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: You are so amazing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The one possibility is to write a function (with `loop`) to the job. Considering the data provided in OP:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(shoptime = c("2013-09-01 08:35:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 08:54:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:07:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-01 09:08:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:11:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:14:00 UTC",
                               "2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-01 09:29:00 UTC", "2013-09-01 09:32:00 UTC"),
                  chosenbrand = c("brand1", "brand1", "brand2", "brand3", "brand5", "brand2", "brand6", "brand2"  ,  "brand2"  ,   "brand4"   ),
                  rank_brand1 = NA,
                  rank_brand2 = NA,
                  rank_brand3 = NA,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Write a function that data.frame and calculate rank
Calculate.Rank <- function(x){
  #loop through each row and calculate count for each brand 
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    #DateTime of the current row. 
    currentrow.time <- as.POSIXlt(x$shoptime[i])
    #calculate number of times brand1 appears
    x$rank_brand1[i] <- nrow(filter(x, as.POSIXlt(shoptime) <= currentrow.time & as.POSIXlt(shoptime) >= (currentrow.time-36*60*60) & chosenbrand == "brand1" ))
    #calculate number of times brand2 appears
    x$rank_brand2[i] <- nrow(filter(x, as.POSIXlt(shoptime) <= currentrow.time & as.POSIXlt(shoptime) >= (currentrow.time-36*60*60) & chosenbrand == "brand2" ))    
    #calculate number of times brand3 appears
    x$rank_brand3[i] <- nrow(filter(x, as.POSIXlt(shoptime) <= currentrow.time & as.POSIXlt(shoptime) >= (currentrow.time-36*60*60) & chosenbrand == "brand3" ))
```

`#Replace the 0 values with NA. I dont think this right approach as one can consider those count to be 0 anyway`

```
    if(x$rank_brand1[i] == 0 ){
      x$rank_brand1[i] = NA
    }

    if(x$rank_brand2[i] == 0 ){
      x$rank_brand2[i] = NA
    }
    if(x$rank_brand3[i] == 0 ){
      x$rank_brand3[i] = NA
    }    

  }

  #Now count of brand1, brand2 and brand3 is available now. Lets calculate rank.
  new.x <- data.frame(x[,1:2], t(apply(-x[,3:5], 1, rank, ties.method='min', na.last = "keep")))

  print(new.x)
}

Calculate.Rank(dat)
```

The resulted data.frame `new.x` will look like:

```
                shoptime chosenbrand rank_brand1 rank_brand2 rank_brand3
1  2013-09-01 08:35:00 UTC      brand1           1          NA          NA
2  2013-09-01 08:54:00 UTC      brand1           1          NA          NA
3  2013-09-01 09:07:00 UTC      brand2           1           2          NA
4  2013-09-01 09:08:00 UTC      brand3           1           2           2
5  2013-09-01 09:11:00 UTC      brand5           1           2           2
6  2013-09-01 09:14:00 UTC      brand2           1           1           3
7  2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC      brand6           2           1           3
8  2013-09-01 09:26:00 UTC      brand2           2           1           3
9  2013-09-01 09:29:00 UTC      brand2           2           1           3
10 2013-09-01 09:32:00 UTC      brand4           2           1           3
```

Comment: Thank you so much but my original data has around 1Million rows. It seems to take too much time. Don't you think so?

Comment: @Johnlegend2 Agree. I wanted to first find a way to achieve the target. Now we need an optimized version. Maybe `arrange` can help.

Comment: If you stick with the `for` loop, I suggest to convert `shoptime` once before calling `Calculate.Rank()`. This will avoid the repeated conversions within the loop. And, the `POSIXlt` class is much less memory efficient than `POSIXct`.