# Count values with a certain condition

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create variables for counting a certain value in previous rows. So for the count_a in 3rd row, I need to count number of "a" in 1st ~ 3rd row. Like this I would like to create `count_a, count_b,count_c,cound_d,count_e` (if unique values of `var1` is `c(a,b,c,d,e)`)

Data:

```
var1     count_a     count_b     count_c ...
  a          0          0          0
  a          1          0          0
  b          2          0          0
  b          2          1          0
  c          2          2          0
  a          2          2          1
  d          3          2          1
  e          3          2          1
```

Here is code for data

I would like to use `setDT(data)` function in `data.table` for this function.

Comment: I have var1 and hope to create second third... column(Count_a,Count_b,...)

Comment: Please accept answer that helped to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP explicitely has asked for a `data.table` solution, here are two slightly different approaches. Note that these are alternative implementations of [PoGibas' `sapply()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47804034/3817004)):

```
library(data.table)
CJ(var1, unique(var1), sorted = FALSE)[
  , cnt := cumsum(shift(V1, fill = "") == V2), by = V2][
    , dcast(.SD, rowid(V2) ~ V2)][, V2 := var1][]
```

> ```
>    V2 a b c d e
> 1:  a 0 0 0 0 0
> 2:  a 1 0 0 0 0
> 3:  b 2 0 0 0 0
> 4:  b 2 1 0 0 0
> 5:  c 2 2 0 0 0
> 6:  a 2 2 1 0 0
> 7:  d 3 2 1 0 0
> 8:  e 3 2 1 1 0
> ```

```
CJ(unique(var1), var1, sorted = FALSE)[
  , cnt := cumsum(V1 == shift(V2, fill = "")), by = rleid(V1)][
    , dcast(.SD, rowid(V1) ~ V1)][, V1 := var1][]


   V1 a b c d e
1:  a 0 0 0 0 0
2:  a 1 0 0 0 0
3:  b 2 0 0 0 0
4:  b 2 1 0 0 0
5:  c 2 2 0 0 0
6:  a 2 2 1 0 0
7:  d 3 2 1 0 0
8:  e 3 2 1 1 0
```

I have also tried to apply the approach used in [this answer to another question of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809119/3817004) but it would require of lot of polishing to get the desired result, here:

```
DT <- data.table(var1)
DT[, rn := .I][DT, on = .(rn < rn), by = .EACHI, .SD[, .(N = .N), by = var1]][
  , dcast(.SD, rn ~ var1, fill = 0)][DT, on = "rn"]
```

> ```
>    rn a b c d NA var1
> 1:  1 0 0 0 0  1    a
> 2:  2 1 0 0 0  0    a
> 3:  3 2 0 0 0  0    b
> 4:  4 2 1 0 0  0    b
> 5:  5 2 2 0 0  0    c
> 6:  6 2 2 1 0  0    a
> 7:  7 3 2 1 0  0    d
> 8:  8 3 2 1 1  0    e
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `cumsum`:

```
# OPs data
foo <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "d", "e")

# Use cumsum to get cumulative sum
# Using dummy variable to get first count as 0
sapply(unique(foo), function(x) cumsum(c("dummy", foo) == x))
#      a b c d e
# [1,] 0 0 0 0 0
# [2,] 1 0 0 0 0
# [3,] 2 0 0 0 0
# [4,] 2 1 0 0 0
# [5,] 2 2 0 0 0
# [6,] 2 2 1 0 0
# [7,] 3 2 1 0 0
# [8,] 3 2 1 1 0
# [9,] 3 2 1 1 1

# Use data.table to join everything (as wanted by OP)
library(data.table)
result <- data.table(foo, 
                     sapply(unique(foo), function(x) cumsum(c("dummy", foo) == x)))
setnames(result, c("var1", paste0("count_", unique(foo))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count_a = cumsum(var1 == "a")
count_a
  [1] 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

This fulfills "count_a in 3rd row, I need to count number of "a" in 1st ~ 3rd row", but that is different from what you have in your example.