# Find rank based on frequency for each row

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr, sapply

My data contain time variable and chosen brand variable as below. time indicates the shopping time and chosenbrand indicates the purchased brand at the time.

With this data, I would like to create third and fourth column in below table. To create the columns here are some rules. Third (fourth) column indicates the rank of brand1 (brand2) based on the frequency of chosen within 5 days. If there is no history within 5days then it should be NA.

For instance, let's see the  5th row. `shoptime` of 5th row is `2013-09-05 09:11:00` then 5day window is `2013-08-31 09:11:00` ~ `2013-09-05 09:11:00`. Within this time period, there have been brand3, bradn3, brand2,
 and brand1 (exclude 5th row's `chosenbrand` ). The rank of the `brand1` (for the third column), based on most frequently chosen, is second and the rank of the `brand2` is also second. So both columns in 5th row should be 2 and 2.

As another example, let's see the last row in below table. `shoptime` of the row is `2013-09-09 09:32:00` then 5day window is `2013-09-04 09:32:00` ~ `2013-09-09 09:32:00`. Within this time period, there have been brand1, bradn2, brand6, brand2 and brand2 (exclude the row's `chosenbrand` ). The rank of the `brand1` (for the third column), based on most frequently chosen, is second and the rank of the `brand2` is the first. So both columns in the row should be 2 and 1.

Is there any simple way?

In addition, if I want to do it by individual (if each customer has several purchased history), how to do that?

Data is as below,

```
   shoptime              chosenbrand  nth_most_freq_brand1 nth_most_freq_brand2 
  2013-09-01 08:35:00       brand3                 NA             NA  
  2013-09-02 08:54:00       brand3                 NA             NA          
  2013-09-03 09:07:00       brand2                 NA             NA          
  2013-09-04 09:08:00       brand1                 NA              2          
  2013-09-05 09:11:00       brand1                 2               2          
  2013-09-06 09:14:00       brand2                 1               2          
  2013-09-07 09:26:00       brand6                 1               1          
  2013-09-08 09:26:00       brand2                 1               2          
  2013-09-09 09:29:00       brand2                 2               1          
  2013-09-09 09:32:00       brand4                 2               1
```

Here is code for data

```
dat <- data.frame(shoptime = c("2013-09-01 08:35:00 UTC", "2013-09-02 08:54:00 UTC", "2013-09-03 09:07:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-04 09:08:00 UTC", "2013-09-05 09:11:00 UTC", "2013-09-06 09:14:00 UTC",
                           "2013-09-07 09:26:00 UTC", "2013-09-08 09:26:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-09 09:29:00 UTC", "2013-09-09 09:32:00 UTC"),
              chosenbrand = c("brand3", "brand3", "brand2", "brand1", "brand1", "brand2", "brand6", "brand2"  ,  "brand2"  ,   "brand4"   ),
              nth_most_freq_brand1 = NA,
              nth_most_freq_brand2 = NA,
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: should I use for loop ? it would take forever because my data size is quite big... any solution?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the OP has asked an almost identical question [How to create a rank variable under certain conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47799054/3817004).

Comment: @Johnlegend2 I have updated my answer and reposted it. I apologize if there are any inconvenience with my previous edits in your post. Clearly, I interpreted your question in the wrong way before.  In the future, if there are anyone incorrectly interpret your post and thus modify your post with conflict to your intent. You absolutely have the right to edit it back and clarify your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP has asked a very similar question ["How to create a rank variable under certain conditions?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47799054/3817004). If I understood correctly, the only differences are

- the extended time range of 5 days instead of 36 hours (note that the OP is referring to *time period*, not date period)
- only `brand1` and `brand2` are to be considered (instead of all values of `chosenbrands`).

Therefore, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809119/3817004) can be reused here with a few adaptions and improvements:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

setDT(dat)[, shoptime := as_datetime(shoptime)]
setorder(dat, shoptime) # not required, just for convenience of observers
selected_brands <- c("brand1", "brand2")
result <- dat[
  .(lb = shoptime - hours(5 * 24), ub = shoptime), 
  on = .(shoptime >= lb, shoptime < ub), 
  nomatch = 0L, by = .EACHI, 
  .SD[, .N, by = chosenbrand][, rank := frank(-N, ties.method="dense")]][
    chosenbrand %in% selected_brands, 
    dcast(unique(.SD[, -1]), shoptime ~ paste0("nth_most_freq_", chosenbrand), 
          value.var = "rank")][
      dat, on = "shoptime"]
# change column order to make it look more similar to the expected answer
setcolorder(result, c(1, 4, 2:3)) 
result
```

> ```
>                shoptime chosenbrand nth_most_freq_brand1 nth_most_freq_brand2
>  1: 2013-09-01 08:35:00      brand3                   NA                   NA
>  2: 2013-09-02 08:54:00      brand3                   NA                   NA
>  3: 2013-09-03 09:07:00      brand2                   NA                   NA
>  4: 2013-09-04 09:08:00      brand1                   NA                    2
>  5: 2013-09-05 09:11:00      brand1                    2                    2
>  6: 2013-09-06 09:14:00      brand2                    1                    2
>  7: 2013-09-07 09:26:00      brand6                    1                    1
>  8: 2013-09-08 09:26:00      brand2                    1                    2
>  9: 2013-09-09 09:29:00      brand2                    2                    1
> 10: 2013-09-09 09:32:00      brand4                    2                    1
> ```

#### Answer to OP's second question

The OP has asked an additional question:

> In addition, if I want to do it by individual (if each customer has several purchased history), how to do that?

Unfortunately, the OP has not provided a sample dataset for this case. So, we need to make up a dataset for two customers based on the provided dataset:

```
dat <- data.frame(shoptime = c("2013-09-01 08:35:00 UTC", "2013-09-02 08:54:00 UTC", "2013-09-03 09:07:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-04 09:08:00 UTC", "2013-09-05 09:11:00 UTC", "2013-09-06 09:14:00 UTC",
                               "2013-09-07 09:26:00 UTC", "2013-09-08 09:26:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-09 09:29:00 UTC", "2013-09-09 09:32:00 UTC"),
                  chosenbrand = c("brand3", "brand3", "brand2", "brand1", "brand1", "brand2", "brand6", "brand2"  ,  "brand2"  ,   "brand4"   ),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat <- rbindlist(list(dat, dat[c(FALSE, TRUE), ]), idcol = "customer")
dat
```

> ```
>     customer                shoptime chosenbrand
>  1:        1 2013-09-01 08:35:00 UTC      brand3
>  2:        1 2013-09-02 08:54:00 UTC      brand3
>  3:        1 2013-09-03 09:07:00 UTC      brand2
>  4:        1 2013-09-04 09:08:00 UTC      brand1
>  5:        1 2013-09-05 09:11:00 UTC      brand1
>  6:        1 2013-09-06 09:14:00 UTC      brand2
>  7:        1 2013-09-07 09:26:00 UTC      brand6
>  8:        1 2013-09-08 09:26:00 UTC      brand2
>  9:        1 2013-09-09 09:29:00 UTC      brand2
> 10:        1 2013-09-09 09:32:00 UTC      brand4
> 11:        2 2013-09-02 08:54:00 UTC      brand3
> 12:        2 2013-09-04 09:08:00 UTC      brand1
> 13:        2 2013-09-06 09:14:00 UTC      brand2
> 14:        2 2013-09-08 09:26:00 UTC      brand2
> 15:        2 2013-09-09 09:32:00 UTC      brand4
> ```

Now, we can modify the exisiting solution to consider different customers:

```
setDT(dat)[, shoptime := as_datetime(shoptime)]
setorder(dat, customer, shoptime) # not required, just for convenience of observers
selected_brands <- c("brand1", "brand2")
result <- dat[
  .(customer = customer, lb = shoptime - hours(5 * 24), ub = shoptime), 
  on = .(customer, shoptime >= lb, shoptime < ub), 
  nomatch = 0L, by = .EACHI, 
  .SD[, .N, by = chosenbrand][, rank := frank(-N, ties.method="dense")]][
    chosenbrand %in% selected_brands, 
    dcast(unique(.SD[, -2]), customer + shoptime ~ paste0("nth_most_freq_", chosenbrand), 
          value.var = "rank")][
            dat, on = .(customer, shoptime)]
# change column order to make it look more similar to the expected answer
setcolorder(result, c(1:2, 5, 3:4)) 
result
```

> ```
>     customer            shoptime chosenbrand nth_most_freq_brand1 nth_most_freq_brand2
>  1:        1 2013-09-01 08:35:00      brand3                   NA                   NA
>  2:        1 2013-09-02 08:54:00      brand3                   NA                   NA
>  3:        1 2013-09-03 09:07:00      brand2                   NA                   NA
>  4:        1 2013-09-04 09:08:00      brand1                   NA                    2
>  5:        1 2013-09-05 09:11:00      brand1                    2                    2
>  6:        1 2013-09-06 09:14:00      brand2                    1                    2
>  7:        1 2013-09-07 09:26:00      brand6                    1                    1
>  8:        1 2013-09-08 09:26:00      brand2                    1                    2
>  9:        1 2013-09-09 09:29:00      brand2                    2                    1
> 10:        1 2013-09-09 09:32:00      brand4                    2                    1
> 11:        2 2013-09-02 08:54:00      brand3                   NA                   NA
> 12:        2 2013-09-04 09:08:00      brand1                   NA                   NA
> 13:        2 2013-09-06 09:14:00      brand2                    1                   NA
> 14:        2 2013-09-08 09:26:00      brand2                    1                    1
> 15:        2 2013-09-09 09:32:00      brand4                   NA                    1
> ```

Comment: thank you always. BTW, if I would like to change the ranking rule such that with the observations having the same rank, the most recently purchased brand has the higher rank, then can you also provide an answer?

Comment: For instance, at 5th row. Both columns in 5th row should be 2 and 3, instead of 2 and 2, because brand 1 is more recent one than brand 2.

Comment: I think I can use the reverse order of "first",,but it seems there is no "last". Do you how to do it? 
Sorry I am not familiar with the package of data.table

Comment: You are welcome. That is an interesting point. `rank()` (from base R) has a `ties.method = "last"` parameter, `frank()` (`data.table`'s fast implementation) does not. So, you may try `rank(-N, ties.method = "last")` or something along `.N - frank(N, ties.method = "first") + 1L` or `rev(frank(rev(-x), ties.method = "first"))`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) and [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate).

#### The OP's First Question

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

***Step 1: Convert the `shoptime` column to date time object***

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(shoptime = ymd_hms(shoptime))
```

***Step 2: Create a look-up table for all the `shoptime`.***

The `complete` function can create all the combinations between columns, so we can create a copy of the `shoptime` column (`shoptime1`) and create all the combinations. Then we can use `filter(shoptime1 > shoptime - hours(5 * 24), shoptime1 < shoptime)` to find date and times are within the 5 days period.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(shoptime1 = shoptime) %>%
  select(contains("shoptime")) %>%
  complete(shoptime, shoptime1) %>%
  filter(shoptime1 > shoptime - hours(5 * 24), shoptime1 < shoptime)
```

***Step 3: Merge `dat` with the look-up table, count the brand, and rank the count numbers.***

We can merge the the look-up table, `dat2`, and `dat` based on `shoptime1` and `shoptime`. The `count` function can count the number of occurrence based on groups. After that, we can group the `shoptime` and use `dense_rank` to create the rank of each brand in each group.

```
dat3 <- dat2 %>%
  left_join(dat, by = c("shoptime1" = "shoptime")) %>%
  count(shoptime, chosenbrand) %>%
  group_by(shoptime) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(n))) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  spread(chosenbrand, rank) %>%
  select(shoptime, brand1, brand2)
```

***Step 4: Merge the original data frame with the `dat3` data frame.***

```
dat4 <- dat %>% left_join(dat3, by = "shoptime")
```

Here is the final result.

```
dat4
#               shoptime chosenbrand brand1 brand2
# 1  2013-09-01 08:35:00      brand3     NA     NA
# 2  2013-09-02 08:54:00      brand3     NA     NA
# 3  2013-09-03 09:07:00      brand2     NA     NA
# 4  2013-09-04 09:08:00      brand1     NA      2
# 5  2013-09-05 09:11:00      brand1      2      2
# 6  2013-09-06 09:14:00      brand2      1      2
# 7  2013-09-07 09:26:00      brand6      1      1
# 8  2013-09-08 09:26:00      brand2      1      2
# 9  2013-09-09 09:29:00      brand2      2      1
# 10 2013-09-09 09:32:00      brand4      2      1
```

#### The OP's Second Question

As OP did not provide an example dataset, I will use the example dataset [Uwe created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103720/7669809). Only a slight modification from my answer 1 will solve this question. The key is to treat the `customer` column as a grouping variable in some steps.

Here is the code to create the example dataset. I only added `as.tibble` in the last to convert the `data.table` object to `tibble`.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.frame(shoptime = c("2013-09-01 08:35:00 UTC", "2013-09-02 08:54:00 UTC", "2013-09-03 09:07:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-04 09:08:00 UTC", "2013-09-05 09:11:00 UTC", "2013-09-06 09:14:00 UTC",
                               "2013-09-07 09:26:00 UTC", "2013-09-08 09:26:00 UTC" ,"2013-09-09 09:29:00 UTC", "2013-09-09 09:32:00 UTC"),
                  chosenbrand = c("brand3", "brand3", "brand2", "brand1", "brand1", "brand2", "brand6", "brand2"  ,  "brand2"  ,   "brand4"   ),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat <- rbindlist(list(dat, dat[c(FALSE, TRUE), ]), idcol = "customer")
dat <- as.tibble(dat)
```

***Step 1: Convert the `shoptime` column to date time object***

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(shoptime = ymd_hms(shoptime))
```

***Step 2: Create a look-up table for all the `shoptime`.***

Notice that the code is almost identical to the previous one except that we need to group `customer` before we apply the `complete` function.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(shoptime1 = shoptime) %>%
  select(contains("shoptime"), customer) %>%
  group_by(customer) %>%
  complete(shoptime, shoptime1) %>%
  filter(shoptime1 > shoptime - hours(5 * 24), shoptime1 < shoptime)
```

***Step 3: Merge `dat` with the look-up table, count the brand, and rank the count numbers.***

Again, we need to consider the `customer` column when we conducted the join operation and count the brand.

```
dat3 <- dat2 %>%
  left_join(dat, by = c("customer", "shoptime1" = "shoptime")) %>%
  count(customer, shoptime, chosenbrand) %>%
  group_by(customer, shoptime) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(-n)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  spread(chosenbrand, rank) %>%
  select(customer, shoptime, brand1, brand2)
```

***Step 4: Merge the original data frame with the `dat3` data frame.***

```
dat4 <- dat %>% left_join(dat3, by = c("customer", "shoptime"))
```

Here is the final result. I added `as.data.frame` just for printing the output with a simpler format.

```
dat4 %>% as.data.frame()
#    customer            shoptime chosenbrand brand1 brand2
# 1         1 2013-09-01 08:35:00      brand3     NA     NA
# 2         1 2013-09-02 08:54:00      brand3     NA     NA
# 3         1 2013-09-03 09:07:00      brand2     NA     NA
# 4         1 2013-09-04 09:08:00      brand1     NA      2
# 5         1 2013-09-05 09:11:00      brand1      2      2
# 6         1 2013-09-06 09:14:00      brand2      1      2
# 7         1 2013-09-07 09:26:00      brand6      1      1
# 8         1 2013-09-08 09:26:00      brand2      1      2
# 9         1 2013-09-09 09:29:00      brand2      2      1
# 10        1 2013-09-09 09:32:00      brand4      2      1
# 11        2 2013-09-02 08:54:00      brand3     NA     NA
# 12        2 2013-09-04 09:08:00      brand1     NA     NA
# 13        2 2013-09-06 09:14:00      brand2      1     NA
# 14        2 2013-09-08 09:26:00      brand2      1      1
# 15        2 2013-09-09 09:32:00      brand4     NA      1
```

Comment: @Uwe Thanks for your comment and great answer. I have updated my answer based on the `tidyverse` framework so it can solve the OP's question and undelete it. I used `hours(5 * 24)` in one of my steps based on your code. I also used your example dataset to show how to do the same operation when there are customers. Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Excellent update. I will delete my comment which referred to your old answer.